# Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext, onchange

In my project I have an `EditText`. I want to count the characters in the `EditText`, and show that number it in a `TextView`. I have written the following code and it works fine. However, my problem is when I click <kbd>Backspace</kbd> it counts up, but I need to decrement the number. How can I consider <kbd>Backspace</kbd>?

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.charCounts);
textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        i++;
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(i) + " / " + String.valueOf(charCounts));
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: Please forgive the irrelevance but I'm curious how you placed the "backspace" in your question formatting? I've asked similar questions where that technique would have been very useful.

Comment: Place your word (in this case Backspace) between <kbd></kbd> tags such as: <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Comment: Whenever you see interesting formatting (like "backspace"), you can always click the "edit" link to see how the author did it. Then just click "cancel" to discard your edit.

Comment: https://github.com/henrychuangtw/AutoInsertEditText

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Use

```
s.length()
```

The following was once suggested in one of the answers, but its very inefficient

```
textMessage.getText().toString().length()
```

Answer (score 38):

how about just getting the length of char in your EditText and display it?

something along the line of

```
tv.setText(s.length() + " / " + String.valueOf(charCounts));
```

Comment: It's even easier than that -- you can just call `textMessage.length()`, no need to do `getText().toString()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#length()

Answer (score 28):

little few change in your code :

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.charCounts);
textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(s.toString().length()));
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: This won't work as written - length() returns an int and setText expects a String

Comment: @MartinLockett use Integer.toString(int_type) to convert string to int.

Answer (score 7):

This is a slightly more general answer with more explanation for future viewers.

### Add a text changed listener

If you want to find the text length or do something else after the text has been changed, you can add a text changed listener to your edit text.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testEditText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count)  {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

The listener needs a [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), which requires three methods to be overridden: `beforeTextChanged`, `onTextChanged`, and `afterTextChanged`.

### Counting the characters

You can get the character count in `onTextChanged` or `beforeTextChanged` with

```
charSequence.length()
```

or in `afterTextChanged` with

```
editable.length()
```

### Meaning of the methods

The parameters are a little confusing so here is a little extra explanation.

**beforeTextChanged**

`beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after)`

- `charSequence`: This is the text content before the pending change is made. You should not try to change it.
- `start`: This is the index of where the new text will be inserted. If a range is selected, then it is the beginning index of the range.
- `count`: This is the length of selected text that is going to be replaced. If nothing is selected then `count` will be `0`.
- `after`: this is the length of the text to be inserted.

**onTextChanged**

`onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count)`

- `charSequence`: This is the text content after the change was made. You should not try to modify this value here. Modify the `editable` in `afterTextChanged` if you need to.
- `start`: This is the index of the start of where the new text was inserted.
- `before`: This is the old value. It is the length of previously selected text that was replaced. This is the same value as `count` in `beforeTextChanged`.
- `count`: This is the length of text that was inserted. This is the same value as `after` in `beforeTextChanged`.

**afterTextChanged**

`afterTextChanged(Editable editable)`

Like `onTextChanged`, this is called after the change has already been made. However, now the text may be modified.

- `editable`: This is the editable text of the `EditText`. If you change it, though, you have to be careful not to get into an infinite loop. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) for more details.

### Supplemental image from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263021/3681880)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TextWatcher maritalStatusTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

```
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        try {
            if (charSequence.length()==0){
                topMaritalStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                topMaritalStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```