# Entering Decimal values in Edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a edit text. i want to enter the decimal values in it.

that is when i have enter a first number. it should be like this: .01

then i have enter a second number. it should be like this: .12

then  for third one. it should be like this: 1.23

it will go like this.... how to implement this scenario. Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a TextWatcher to the EditText. This will notify you when the text changes.

When you know the text has changed, you can run it through a DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But i could notfind a better logic to implement this scneario. Please Help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to look for modifications to the value in the field and insert a decimal point in the appropriate position as they type. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener) for an example of using a TextWatcher.

Comment: I believe there's sample code in the SO question I linked to. There are a ton of examples of usage of TextWatcher on Google Code also: http://code.google.com/query/#q=textwatcher

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But i could notfind a better logic to implement this scneario. Please Help on this.