# Take EditText with decimals value for preforming mathematics 

Tags: java, android

All-
I have an EditText field where the user enters a currency value (eg. "120.45"). I need to take that value and use it in an equation. The problem is, the decimal point gets ignored so instead of multiplying 120.45 by 2 it multiples 12,045 by 2. Is there any way to make the equation see this value as "120.45".
Here is my XML:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_bill"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_dollar_sign" 
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/view_dollar_sign" 
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="@string/edit_bill"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:maxLength="6" 
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_dollar_sign"
     />
```

Here is my code:

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_bill);             
    String value = text.getText().toString();       
    if(!value.contains("."))
        value = "."+value;
    float bill = Float.parseFloat(value);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "the decimal point gets ignored" by what? Are you trying to parse it to an Integer? Do you have a special inputType set on your EditText? Post the XML for your EditText and explain how you're retrieving the value.

Comment: refer this previous post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854360/entering-decimal-values-in-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your strings to floats or doubles first, e.g.

```
    x = Double.parseDouble(editTextName.getText().toString());
```

Then perform operations as necessary!

Afterwards you could could change it back to a output TextView like this:

```
 answerTextView.setText("" + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

**remove if condition from yourcode**

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_bill);             
    String value = text.getText().toString();       
    // if(!value.contains("."))   <---REMOVE THESE LINES
       //  value = "."+value;    <---REMOVE THESE LINES
    float bill = Float.parseFloat(value);
```