# ontextchange android

Tags: android

I need the method or the action when the EditText changed. When the user write in EditText I want to have some action. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View.setOnKeyListener()`, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener%28android.view.View.OnKeyListener%29).

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods you can register

```
beforeTextChanged
onTextChanged
afterTextChanged
```

Example reference: [Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener)

Answer (score 0):

I always do it with a TextWatcher, and overriding the `afterTextChanged` like this:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String newText = editable.toString();
    }
});
```