# How to pause between lines of code

Tags: android

Okay I have a text view that changed every time a user types in an answer or response. I dont want the computers response to appear automatically but maybe pause for 3 to 5 seconds with a prograss dialog, or something to show its processing data, when its really not. 
What would i implement in my code to do this. Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're just wasting the user's time. Why?

Comment: To look like a badass software company with 'heavy' apps.

Answer (score 1):

for this I would create a timer that will disable the text view after they have finished doing what they want and then enable it again after x number of seconds. You could even create the timer with a random length of time between 3 and 5 seconds so it seems random.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks sounds like what i need!

Comment: To help you guys better understand what im trying to do. Here is an example   public void onCreate(){

Comment: To help you guys better understand what im trying to do. Here is an example 

public void onCreate(){  
     
     setContentView(r.layout.main)
textView.setText("Welcome enter your name");
// The user enters there name in the EditText box

respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){

//Once the user enters there name i would like it to pause and display a progress dialog before the next textView.


I hope this makes more since what im trying to do. 
Thanks for Everyone help!




}

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) within which you would call `Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(2)+3)` in the `doInBackground()` method.  Within the AsyncTask class, you can show and hide the progress bar with the [onPreExecute() and onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Probably .. this solution [Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listenerand) invoking a thread for controlling progress dialog can solve your problem

Comment: Okay thank!So im trying to implement the a handler for a postDeleay. After the button is clicked. Do you think this will work?

Comment: could you give me an example.