# Verify that EditText is empty and waiting User entering data

Tags: android, events, android-edittext

My layout is:

```
1 EditText (id = etvalue1)
1 EditText (id = etvalue2)
1 Button (id = save)
```

I need to know how to do the following with these widgets:

- If the User clicks on the button with the EditText empty display a message and wait for the User to enter the value.
- Display the message until the User and enter the value after the value is to enter the calculation (`etvalue1` + `etvalue2`) and show the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onclicklistener for the button do the following

```
if(edit1.getText().equals("") || edit2.getText().equals(""))  
{
     //toast the error message 
     return;
}
 //calculate the result
```

The maximum time for toast is Toast.LENGTH_LONG. If you want the message to be displayed till the user enters data in edittext, then use a textview to display the message. Set onTextChangedListener on both the EditTexts to check if the text is changed. in afterTextChanged method you can do the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

In Activity Class write this code in onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etvalue1);
    editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etvalue2);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!(editText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))){
                if(!(editText2.getText().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    addNumbers();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Enter no.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Enter no.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        private void addNumbers() {

        }
    });

}
```

}

In addNumbers method get the value from EditTest and do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(edit1.getText().equals("") || edit2.getText().equals(""))  
{
     //toast the error message 
     Dialog dialog=new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
     LinearLayout llView=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
     EditText editText1=new EditText(getApplicationContext());
     EditText editText2=new EditText(getApplicationContext());
     wsutText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //do your calculations
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    }); 

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //do your calculations
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    }); 
llView.addView(editText1);
llView.addView(editText2);
dialog.setContentView(llView);
dialog.show();
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to detect when the user enters values in the `edittext`**, you need to use events to observe the changes as in [Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener)

Read the relevant methods in the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

**Alternatively**, you can just make that check on the click event of your button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(etvalue1.getText().toString().equals(''))
                     //empty text condition
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to determine if the EditText is empty:

```
String sEdit1 = Edit1.getText().toString();

if (sEdit1.matches(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "EditText is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(edit1.getText().equals("") || edit1.getText().equals(null))  {
    //toast the message 
} else {
    //calculate the result
}
```