Which function in android studio (java) lets me to create a listener for views which are in a finger path
I work with Java in Android Studio, if in app, the finger goes on a path from button A to  button C, and for example button B is in the middle of this path, then how can I create a listener for button B to show a reaction? Remember that I haven't clicked on button B directly and this was just in a middle of the way that the finger has passed from
I have tested onClickListener,onTouchListener and lots of things but I couldn't do it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625775/android-on-focus-change
