# how to persist data in editText using Shared Preferences in android

Tags: java, android

I have simple editText in which user enters number or string.
I want to persist that number or string when user again enters the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.first save this into `preference` like this

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString(MY_NAME, edittext.getText().toString());
        prefsEditor.putString(MY_WALLPAPER, "f664.PNG");
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

2.Now second time you will get through whenever you get use this

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_NAME, 0);
        String wallPaper = myPrefs.getString(MY_WALLPAPER, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could do something similar to this: [Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener)

Then, once you have detected that the text has changed, you can save it to your `SharedPreferences`.

Alternatively, if you only want to persist when the user leaves/enters the app, then you could just override the `onPause()` method of your Activity to save to your `SharedPreferences`.  Just use `<EditText>.getText()` to get the String entered and then save that.  Override `onResume()` and then use `<EditText>.setText(<String from SharedPreference>)` to restore it upon entering your app.

I'm assuming you know how to use SharedPreferences, but let me know if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

This code will persist the data when the user removes focus from the EditText Box using the OnFocusChangeListener;

```
EditText userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ID_HERE);
SharedPreferences pref = this.getPreferences(this.MODE_PRIVATE);

String data_key = "data";

View.OnFocusChangeListener persistData = new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!hasFocus){
            EditText e = (EditText)v;
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
            edit.putString(data_key,e.getText().toString());
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

};

userInput.setOnFocusChangeListener(persistData);
```