# Filehandling Save,Edit,View and Delete data

Tags: android, file-handling

I am writing a program which asks the user to enter name, age and country and should save the data in a file. The user should be able to delete, edit and view the data.

the output should be like this.

[image]

When I save the data it is stored in one text file. For example the user inputted the following. Name:  John Wall, Age: 23, Country: Canada then it will save in a text file as "John 23 Country". How can I able to load those data in their specific text box?

Comment: Please used database instead of save data in text file.

Comment: I am required to save it in a text file using File Handling in Android.

Comment: whenever you enter edittext fiels it store into sharedprefense and whever get thats value prfer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831287/how-to-persist-data-in-edittext-using-shared-preferences-in-android/11831469#11831469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options

1. Write the contents to a database. A tutorial on writing to SQL lite should get your started [1]
2. If the information is meant for light weight storage (say this is just one entry) use shared preferences / file based persistence [2]

[1] - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

[2] - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html