# What am I doing wrong while trying to make a TextView show what I write in an EditText?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.realapptest1.MESSAGE";

TextView test;
EditText edittext;
String spokenwordstring;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.spokenmsg);
    spokenwordstring = edittext.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void registermessage(View view) {
    test.setText(spokenwordstring);

}
```

Basically I am trying to show whatever I write in an EditText on a TextView with the code above but I am not succeeding.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should create a button in your xml and set its onClick method to perform the action that you want, registermessage().

Comment: there is a properly working button that has android:onClick(registermessage);, i can succeed using test.setText("anything); inside public void registermessage

Comment: This is probably an answered [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener) you may be looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter some text in the `EditText` your variable `spokenwordstring` will not get updated. The variable is not bound to the value in your `EditText`.

To get this working you need to do a `getText()` on your `EditText`. 
Try this.

```
public void registermessage(View view) {
  spokenwordstring = edittext.getText().toString();
  test.setText(spokenwordstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public void registermessage(View view) {
  spokenwordstring = edittext.getText().toString(); //remove this from onCreate
  test.setText(spokenwordstring);
}
```

When you put `spokenwordstring = edittext.getText().toString();` in your onCreate, you are saving the value of the `EditText` at the time of creation, which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `spokenwordstring = edittext.getText().toString();` in your o`onCreate` method. The problem with this is that the information has not yet been entered into the `EditText`. So call that line from the method `registerMessage()` before calling `setText`.

Answer (score 0):

You said there is a button that works, but I don't see it in your code. As an alternative, you can add a `OnKeyListener` to your EditText and use it to update the TextView when the user uses a direction key or hits the enter key. (You would have to check the key codes in the listener.)