# list.getchildAt(i) return null pointer ,only shows visible views not shows more

Tags: android

I have a list view, in that list view, I have  30 items with edit text in which I manually put the value and after that I calculate  the total of value set on edit text for 30 items. But problems is it calculate the total of only visible list items which are almost 10 and I need all 30 values of edit text.after 10 items view become null.
How to resolve this problem.

```
totalpoints.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /*for (int i = 0; i < summaryList.size(); i++) 
            {
                summaryList.get();

            }*/

            for (int i = 0; i < listView_subCategory.getCount(); i++) {
                view = listView_subCategory.getChildAt(i);
                if (view == null) {


                } else {
                    try {
                        EditText text = (EditText) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.et_date);
                        TextView tv_productname=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_userName);

                        String points = text.getText().toString().trim();
                        String productname=tv_productname.getText().toString().trim();
                        int point = Integer.valueOf(points);
                        count_summary = count_summary + point;
                        String truetotal = Integer.toString(count_summary);
                        et_total.setText(truetotal);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Fill Value First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast1.show();
                    }

                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }

    });
```

Comment: In your Adapter, use `getItem(position)` to retrieve a child object.

Comment: i retrieved but it calculate only visible count and  don't give any thing ,i need the object of invisible item ,but problem is view it shows null then how can get value from edit text which set on that view.

Comment: Thats normal, your object is not really allocated in momery if its not visible, so you should use an ArrayList to store your objects et try to edit text of object by using this Array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should think fo a better approach than iterating over the `EditText`s with `getChildAt()` to collect all the value. 
I take it that the user can change the values in the EditTexts, you can have an `Array` of size 30 of Values and everytime the user enters / changes a value you change the according value in the `Array`. Use a listener that changes the values in your Array like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener).

Comment: its working some what but i cannot get value for all elements in list it still showing calculation of 10 items .