# Dynamically Changing the Text between EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two edittext fields in a layout. When i type something in edittext1, the same text should get filled up in edittext2 dynamically and vice versa. How can i do that??

Comment: Give a look to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener, maybe is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You add [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to both the Edittext as follows

```
    EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
EditText myOutputBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myOutputBox);
      myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int count, int after) {
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int before, int count) {
       myOutputBox.setText(s);
       }
      });
```

Similarly for other Edittext.

```
 myOutputBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int count, int after) {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int before, int count) {
           myTextBox.setText(s);
           }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EditText#addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29). All you need to do is update the desired `EditText` inside `afterTextChanged` method.