# restrict android EditText for a particular word

Tags: android

hey i want  to restrict my edittext input ..i want  that user cannot add any & into the edittext..is it possible? if yes please help... here is my edit text code..

```
EditText descriptions = new EditText(this);
        allEds.add(descriptions);
        descriptions.setHint("Descriptions");
        descriptions.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        if("0".equals(partial_check)){ descriptions.setEnabled(true); }else{ descriptions.setEnabled(false); }
        linearLayout.addView(descriptions);
```

Comment: is there any particular word or many words ..

Comment: i only restrict **&** insertion through textinput

Comment: onTextchanged Listener can do the job for you. Check substring on every text entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
descriptions.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == '&') {
              descriptions.setText(s.subSequence(0, s.length() - 1));
              descriptions.setSelection(s.length() - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an edittext *Ontextchanged* listener for this. There check whether the current text contains an & character. If it does, remove it and reset the edittext with the string without the & character.

This link will give you some idea of the exact usage:
[Counting Chars in EditText Changed Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener)

Answer (score 0):

As Gautham said use OntextChangedListener for this kind of problem which will check each letter after insertion and help you to restrict. Something like:

```
        descriptions .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //restrict the word here...

        }
    });
```

For some extra information about ontextChanged and TextWatcher [Tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-11-using-textwatcher-in-android/) and also the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did it like by using input filter, you can change it to your needs

```
InputFilter filter= new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            String checkMe = String.valueOf(source.charAt(i));

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+0123456789]");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(checkMe);
            boolean valid = matcher.matches();
            if(!valid){
                Log.d("", "invalid");
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

here  `"[+0123456789]"` in the line `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+0123456789]");`
is what will be accepted.now for your edit text set this filter

```
yourEditTexy.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```